# Problem opening ports on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, iptables, ufw

I am trying to open several ports on my computer running Ubuntu 16.04, which would allow me to run drone simulation software on it and connect to it a companion computer (Odroid).

I have tried opening the ports using `sudo ufw allow PORT#/tcp`, but when I try connecting or run `netcat -v 127.0.0.1 PORT#` I get a `Connection refused` prompt. The same goes if I try connecting over the local network using my computer's IP instead of the loopback.

What could be blocking the ports?

Using `sudo ufw status verbose` I get:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
PORT#1/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
PORT#2/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
PORT#3/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
PORT#1/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
PORT#2/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
PORT#3/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Using `sudo iptables -L` I am able to locate the three ports:

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:PORT#1
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:PORT#2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:PORT#3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing seems to be *blocking* your PORT#. Your output clearly shows that it's not a firewall issue.

A default install of Ubuntu has no exploitable listening services, so the default firewall settings are to [ACCEPT] all connections.

The likeliest answer is that you simply don't have any service listening on PORT# to receive the connection. Applications listen on specific ports - that's how the systems know which packet is meant for which application.

If a packet arrives addressed to a port that nothing is listening on, then system doesn't know what to do with the packet, and sends a 'reject' back to the sender. You seem to be looking at such a 'reject' message.

Nomenclature:

- You OPEN ports in the firewall by changing the firewall rules.
- Applications BIND TO and LISTEN ON ports, receiving packets that have already passed through the firewall.

History: Firewalls became a big deal on systems that had built-in exploitable listening services that admins could not control or disable any other way. A stock install of Ubuntu does not have any of those (if you discover one, please file a bug report. We don't like those).

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. The problem is a bit specific, but maybe something will spring to your mind: when I run the drone simulator (Dronekit-sitl) on the PC I can run my Python script locally (loopback + port) or on the companion computer (PC's IP + port). When I run an extending software allowing multiple connections (MAVproxy) I am able to run multiple scripts locally (loopback, each has its own port), but when I try to acces one of the unoccupied ports from the companion computer, I get a 'connection refused' error message. Does this sound familiar in any way?